# Protocol Enumerable not implemented for MyApp.MyStruct

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to create a join table, and I'm running into this error while trying to build a struct.

#### ERROR

protocol Enumerable not implemented for %Statcasters.UsersLeagues{**meta**: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:built, "users_leagues">, commissioner: nil, id: nil, inserted_at: nil, league: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded, league_id: nil, updated_at: nil, user: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded, user_id: nil}. This protocol is implemented for: DBConnection.PrepareStream, DBConnection.Stream, Date.Range, Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Stream, File.Stream, Function, GenEvent.Stream, HashDict, HashSet, IO.Stream, List, Map, MapSet, Postgrex.Stream, Range, Stream, Timex.Interval

It's failing on this line:

#### LEAGUE CONTROLLER:

```
  def new(conn, _params) do
    changeset = League.changeset(%League{users_leagues: %UsersLeagues{}})

    render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
  end
```

I have a has_many through relationship with leagues and users. The join table is the users_leages table and that is what I'm trying to create in the new action. But when I try to load the new page. it breaks with this error.

Comment: Try changing `%UsersLeagues{}` to `[%UsersLeagues{}]`.

Comment: That worked! But I don't understand why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error means that Ecto tried to use the value of the field `users_leagues` as an Enumerable which `%UsersLeagues{}` isn't. Since the field is a `has_many` field, a record can have many of them and it needs to be a list (or more specifically an Enumerable) of `%UsersLeagues{}` structs.

You can fix this by wrapping `%UsersLeagues{}` in a list:

```
changeset = League.changeset(%League{users_leagues: [%UsersLeagues{}]})
```